# Gnome Boxes on Fedora 33 fails to open

Tags: fedora, gnome

I attempt to load gnome-boxes from the terminal (I'm running Fedora 33) and get the following error

```
$ gnome-boxes

(gnome-boxes:3194): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:34:57.343: GtkFlowBox with a model will ignore sort and filter functions

(gnome-boxes:3194): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:34:57.344: GtkListBox with a model will ignore sort and filter functions

(gnome-boxes:3194): Boxes-WARNING **: 12:34:57.904: libvirt-machine.vala:83: Failed to disable 3D Acceleration

(gnome-boxes:3194): Boxes-WARNING **: 12:34:57.913: libvirt-broker.vala:70: Failed to update domain 'fedora33-wor-2': Failed to set domain configuration: XML error: Invalid PCI address 0000:04:00.0. slot must be >= 1

(gnome-boxes:3194): Boxes-CRITICAL **: 12:34:57.916: boxes_vm_importer_get_source_media: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

My system:

```
$uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 5.9.16-200.fc33.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Dec 21 14:08:22 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I don't whether it's related but I recently updated from kernel 5.9.11 directly to 5.9.16 (haven't used the PC in question for some weeks) and before gnome-boxes was working as normal.

Please advise how I can restore gnome-boxes - I have some virtual machines that I need to access...

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue when I force stopped Gnome-Boxes while cloning a VM.

Deleting the conflicting VM will resolve your issue(in your case 'fedora33-wor-2').

To delete the VM in fedora, install "libvirt-client" which provides "virsh" using the command

```
    dnf install libvirt-client
```

then double check the available VM's using

```
    virsh list --all
```

Delete the VM using command,

```
    virsh undefine VM_Name
```

Comment: If you encounter `Requested operation is not valid: cannot undefine domain with nvram` use `virsh undefine --nvram VM_Name`

Answer (score 2):

@channel-fun solved the problem of staring up gnome-boxes.

But the real problem is in cloning procedure. The XML describing the new machine is malformed.

`virt-clone --original fedora33-ser --auto-clone`

works properly.

Answer (score 1):

Extending on Channel Fun's answer for Ubuntu repos the package is `libvirt-clients` *(note the plural s)*:

```
sudo apt install libvirt-clients
```

Check the available VM's using:

```
virsh list --all
```

Delete the VM using:

```
virsh undefine VM_Name
```

If you receive the error:

> error: Refusing to undefine while domain managed save image exists

Then you can explicitly remove that also using the `--managed-save` flag:

```
virsh undefine VM_Name --managed-save
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I had the same problem recently.
I shut down gnome boxes whilst it was cloning a vm, and shutdown the machine.
I then couldn't open boxes, as it would just crash.
I was able to delete the VM itself, and then deleted the XML file associated with it.
To delete the VM itself, go to :

```
$HOME/.var/app/org.gnome.Boxes/data/gnome-boxes/images (which in my case is a symbolic link to a data drive)
```

and delete the VM with the name that you were cloning to (or safer, just move it somewhere).

To delete the XML file associated with it:

```
$HOME/.var/app/org.gnome.Boxes/config/libvirt/qemu/
```

and delete (or safer move) the file that is named VM_NAME.xml.

Then boxes should open ok, at least it worked for me.

Comment: installing libvirt-client didn't work

Comment: I'm using Fedora Silverblue, so this was great. I didn't need to toolbox or install anything :) Thanks for this solution.